# Snappy Ubuntu Core 64 bit

Tags: application-development, 64-bit, raspberrypi

Is the image for Raspberry pi 3 a 64-bit OS?
(http://releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/16/ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img.xz)

Comment: Are you asking about _snappy_ or _raspberry_.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the kernel that comes with it, it is using Ubuntu-Core kernel 4.4.0-1030 https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi2/4.4.0-1030.37 which is showing that it's architecture is `armhf` in which it looks to be 32 bit.

---

From this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125314/111521 :

> ARM processors have a completely different instruction set. You cannot
>   install an x86 or x86-64 package on an ARM system. You need a package
>   for ARM, for the correct instruction set, and more generally for the
>   correct ABI. There are no major 64-bit distributions for 64-bit ARM
>   processors yet, because the ARMv8 architecture revision which
>   introduces a 64-bit instruction set is still very new and not commonly
>   available. There are however multiple 32-bit ABIs, which assume the
>   existence of different processor features and use different versions
>   of the argument-passing convention. The main ARM ABIs used on Linux
>   are:
>
> - armel, based on the ARM EABI version 2 (known as “ARM EABI” or “EABI”
>     for short), in its little-endian incarnation;
> - armhf, which is a
>     variant of armel that takes advantage of some features of newer ARM
>     CPUs, in particular hardware floating-point support.

---

Also look here for more information:  https://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort

This shows 32 bit as well:  https://wiki.debian.org/ArmPorts

---

Hope this helps!